# Validate ASP.NET MVC model to contain only a single email address using RegularExpressionAttribute

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to validate a string containing only a single email address. The string value comes from an ASP.NET MVC textbox. The input text *may* contains multiple email addresses separated by a comma, a semicolon or a whitespace. Examples:

- abc@abc.com (True)
- abc@abc.com;def@abc.com (False)
- abc@abc.com,def@abc.com (False)
- abc@abc.com def@abc.com (False)
- abc@abc.com;def@abc.com;ghi@abc.com (False)

The following expression does not work in my case:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?!;|,)$
```

The model validation is done using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute`. Example:

```
[RegularExpression(@"expr")]
public string SingleEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: `input.Where(c => c == '@').Count() > 1` ?

Comment: Sounds as if he wants to check for separators between the emails, not the @.

Comment: @GrantWinney I just want to check whether there are multiple email addresses separated by semicolons, commas etc.

Comment: The expression you tried doesn't work...how so? What result are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not trying to validate the email addresses, then forget the `Regex` statement. That's for advanced pattern matching, and all you're trying to do is look for a few characters.

Use [`IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) to find the first occurrence of any of those characters. If one's found, you have multiple emails. (Assuming there isn't a delimiter on the end of the string with no email address after it.)

```
var hasMultipleEmails = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)
                            && input.IndexOfAny(new[] { ',', ';', ' ' }) > -1;
```

Or use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option to take care of stray delimiters.

```
var hasMultipleEmails = input.Split(new[] { ',', ';', ' ' },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count() > 1;
```